# accessing unallocatted memory after changing matrix size

Tags: c, math, memory, matrix, jagged-arrays

I won't bother you with all the dry details of what is the assignment and the problem I'm trying to solve, I'll cut right to the chase.

I need to fill a matrix with data. the matrix is square and everything is zero except the first 2 diagonals (meaning `M[i][i]` for `i` between 0 and n-1 and `M[i][i+1]` for `i` between 0 and n-2 are already filled)

We want to fill the matrix using this a bit complex formula.

```
M[i][j]=max(a+min(M[i+2][j],M[i+1][j-1]) , b+min(M[i+1][j-1],M[i][j-2]))
```

The result is an upper triangular matrix. You can see from the above formula that to compute the k'th diagonal, we need the k-2 diagonal. And I said the first 2 are given.

I wrote a code to fill the matrix and it is working as intended.

**Here is my problem:**

Since it is an upper triangular matrix, the lower half is all zero. so there is no point in wasting memory and saving it. So I thought to myself instead of allocating an n by n matrix, I will allocate n rows, and to the first row ill allocate n spaces, to the second n-1, to the third n-2 and so on...

But since we changed the dimensions of the matrix, the formula I wrote above to compute `M[i][j]` is different now. In my opinion, we moves all the values in the `i'th` row, `i` columns to the left. in row 0 nothing changed. in row 1, we pulled all the values 1 column to the left, etc. So if I understand correctly:

```
M[i][j]=M'[i][j-i]
```

Where `M'` is our new matrix. And so plugging that in the formula above:

```
M'[i][j]=max(a+min(M'[i+2][j-i],M'[i+1][j-1-i]) , b+min(M'[i+1][j-1-i],M'[i][j-2-i]))
```

However now the program to fill the matrix is not working correctly. It is filling the matrix with garbage.

Here is the code to fill the matrix:

```
void fill_matrix() //fills the matrix with data of optimal path, we use memoization rather than recursion, so this step is necessary. 
{ //first step is to allocate the matrix. we can assume right_index==size-1 since this is the first thing we do after generating the array
    int i,j;
    optimum_matrix=(int**)malloc((right_index+1)*sizeof(int**));
    for(j=0;j<=right_index;j++)
        optimum_matrix[j]=(int*)malloc((right_index+1-j)*sizeof(int*)); //matrix allocated. upper triangular matrix. no need to allocate n^2 spaces. //to fix indices, M[i][j]=M'[i][j-i+1]. subtract i and add 1 to each column, since we moved each entry in row i, i-1 columns back.
    for(i=0;i<=right_index;i++) //first diagonal
        optimum_matrix[i][0]=data_array[i];
    for(i=0;i<right_index;i++) //second diagonal
        optimum_matrix[i][1]=get_max(data_array[i],data_array[i+1]);
    for(i=0;i<=right_index;i++)
    {
        for(j=2;j<=right_index-i;j++)
            optimum_matrix[i][j]=get_max(data_array[i]+get_min(optimum_matrix[i+2][j-i],optimum_matrix[i+1][j-i-1]),data_array[j]+get_min(optimum_matrix[i+1][j-i-1],optimum_matrix[i][j-i-2])); //here is the problem
    }
}
```

And this is the code to print the matrix

```
void print_matrix()
{
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=0;i<=right_index;i++)
    {
        for(k=0;k<i;k++)
            printf("0 ");
        for(j=0;j<=right_index-i;j++)
            printf("%d ",optimum_matrix[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Even on the first iteration of filling the third diagonal, when it enters the for loop where it says "here is the problem", if i type `printf("%d",optimum_matrix[i+2][j-i]);` it will print garbage. And I don't understand why since the formula agrees.

Would appreciate help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
optimum_matrix=(int**)malloc((right_index+1)*sizeof(int**));
```

That isn't the right way to allocate a double array. It's allocating only one dimension of the double array. It's hard for me to follow your logic on how big you want each row and column to be. So below may not be the exact right dimensions you want. But hopefully it does illustrate how to more correctly allocate the double array.

```
int **optimum_matrix = malloc((right_index+1)*sizeof(int*));

for (i = 0; i < (right_index+1); i++) {
    optium_matrix[i] = malloc((right_index+1)*sizeof(int));
}
```

BTW, I left out the check of the malloc return value for brevity. And your original code also doesn't check the return value of malloc. That should always be done.

Comment: You are correct that I allocated memory incorrectly. But that didnt make a difference as size(int)=size(int*)=size(int**). the allocation is fine. Also I found the problem, it was indeed with the formula. Thank for the help.

Comment: Good that you found the problem. But the allocation is still a problem. Notice that the sample has two malloc calls (the second in a for loop which means a lot more mallocs). So the total size is not equivalent to your original code.